# how to define suitable coefficients?

Tags: python-3.x, function, optimization, coefficients

I have a dataframe like this:

`data = pd.DataFrame({ 'l': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'F': [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], })`

1. I have calculated (coulmn l - coulmn F)^2 and put result in new column for each row
   2)Then I have calculated the average of that column, for example the averagre is x.

Now I want to have a column called coefficient and select the coefficients so that the average of the following formula (y) is less than the previous average, with the same procedure for x:
(coulmn l - coefficient*coulmn F)^2

goal: y<x
question:  how to identify coefficients?

here is my code and it seems correct but does not work:

```
x = np.mean((data['l'] - data['F'])**2)

while True:
    
    coefficients = np.random.uniform(0, 5, size=len(data))
    
    
    result_data['coefficients'] = coefficients
    result_data['estimated_squared_diff'] = (data['l'] - coefficients * data['F'])**2
    y = np.mean(result_data['estimated_squared_diff'])

    
    if y < x:
        break

print(result_data['coefficients'])
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.